# Adding collections from different instances

Tags: collections, smalltalk

I am new to Smalltalk and I am trying to do a very simple program that would produce a single collection, out of multiple collections in this way:

Let's say I have a Set of Armories, and every Armory has it's own Weapons Set, what I would like to do is to write a method that would return a single collection with all the Weapons from every Armory combined.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
armories inject: OrderedCollection new into: [:collection :armory |
   collection addAll: armory weapons; yourself].
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate! sorry for my ignorance, but what is the ;yourself for ?

Comment: First, inject:into: uses the inject parameter (the OrderedCollection) as the first parameter of the block and on subsequent loops, it uses the result of the block.  The block, therefore, has to answer the collection.  The addAll: method doesn't return the collection it added to (collection) but rather the collection it added (armory weapons). The yourself is there to make sure that we use the collection as the return value of the block rather than the collection of weapons that we just added to that collection.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to improve David's answer by proposing this solution:

```
armories inject: OrderedCollection new into: [:allWeapons :armory |
  allWeapons, armory weapons]
```

As `,` returns concatenation of 2 collections.

Now also there is sort of more "fluid" way without creation of new *OrderedCollection*. There is a method called `fold:` or `reduce:` or 'reduceLeft:` which is a concept from functional programming. So you can do:

```
(armories collect: #weapons) fold: [allWeapons :weapons |
  allWeapons, weapons]
```

So `armories collect: #weapons` will give you a collections of collections of weapons. `fold:` takes 1st element and 2nd and executes the block on them. Then in take a result and a 3rd element, and so on…

Now the best solution that I know  is `flatCollect:`. I'm sure that it's present in [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo), but may be missing from other smalltalk based languages. This is the same as `collect:` but flattens the result one level. So all you have to do is:

```
armories flatCollect: #weapons
```

Enjoy

Comment: I agree that the last one is nicest, but like you said, may not be as portable. Of course, this is Smalltalk! So the best portable answer could be: "#flatCollect: aBlock ^ self davidBucksOriginalAnswer: aBlock". As to your other two suggestions, I wouldn't call the first an improvement. It copies the collection on each iteration, seemingly just to save the #yourself send. The second does the same, and adds iterating over the armory twice. If they were significantly more intention revealing, maybe. But IMHO neither is an improvement on David's...

Comment: @SeanDeNigris usually I prefer prettier code to faster one :)

Comment: Ha ha. While commenting, I was thinking that very same thing! Even in such small cases, writing faster but uglier code can be premature optimization. If we had started with your suggestion #1 or #3, & someone then suggested David's, I would've made that point & favored either of those. My point was that I didn't think #1 was "prettier enough" to justify, & if we were at a dance, I would avoid #2 completely, lol ;)

Comment: I would just use #flatCollect: on Pharo, and implement it on the other platforms where we need to run. In that case, it becomes our own little library method, which may be called in a variety of circumstances, and David's implementation or Stephan's stream approach (very similar to #flatCollect:'s actual implementation), become clear winners IMHO...

Comment: @SeanDeNigris so for me it's more about verbosity. Because in general you say let's start with empty collection and on each step evaluate this thing… And in my variant it's: "concatenation of our collection and current weapon set" while in David's its: "adding weapons to the current collection and returning collection itself". Also in my 2nd option is: "collect weapons form armouries and then fold the collection by concatenating previous weapons with a current set". Maybe it's wrong to think in this way, but this is why I like functional programming :)

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is the classic smalltalk idiom. When doing more complex combinations you might prefer a stream based approach:

```
OrderedCollection fromStream: [:allWeapons |
    allWeapons nextPutAll: armories collect: [:armory | armory weapons]]
```